# How to set the progress bar to work till either content is loaded or a max time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

I would like to have a progress bar for the entrance of my page. So it must have two goals, first tries to load content of the page, then in the second plan completes after 10 seconds (even if the content is not loaded yet).

I have made a simple progress bar but to me honest don't know how it calculates the time:

```
var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
  progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

progressbar.progressbar({
  value: false,
  change: function() {
    progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
  },
  complete: function() {
    progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
  }
});

function progress() {
  var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

  progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );

  if ( val < 99 ) {
    setTimeout( progress, 100 );
  }
}

setTimeout( progress, 3000 );
```

HTML:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div class="progress-label">Loading...</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qCCzE/6/)**

Currently it does not work with the page's contents. But how can I make it the way to work until everything is loaded in the page, But in any case takes 5 seconds minimum and 10 second maximum to load?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of the progress bar knowing how big the page will be and what % of it has loaded.

If you want to implement this, I would suggest having every element in your page in a javascript object, all the CSS, Javascript and Images. You could loop through and append these to the DOM one at a time and the progress bar would indicate how many files out of how many total have been loaded.

I prefer simply having a loading GIF over the page in a modal, then when the document has loaded you can remove the loading GIF.

Comment: Ok thanks, the first way sounds complicated and actually not efficient in my case. But in your second suggestion you mentioned when the document has loaded, isn't it the same as loading the whole content of the document? An I can you give me an example either on here or JSFiddle to see how it works? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will not fire until the entire document has finished loading.

Your modal loading div:

< div id="loading" style="position:absolute; background-color:black; top:0px; right:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; background-image:url(loading.gif); background-position:center center; background-repeat:none" >< /div>

jQuery (fires when page has loaded):
$(function() { $("#loading").remove(); });

Comment: Great. Thanks. IS it possible to have a minimum and maximum time too? like if the page has no content but still takes 5 seconds at least, and stop at 10 seconds even if loading the page hasnt finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a timer like this that would remove the div after 10 seconds

var maxTime = 10; /* Seconds */
var myTime = 0;
var myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    myTime++;
    if (myTime >= maxTime) {
       myTimer.clear();
       $("#loading").remove();
    }

}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you can try this get ajax loader http://www.ajaxload.info/. What I then did was add a div right below the `<body>` tag with a class spinner `<div class="spinner"></div>`. Here is the class css 
`.spinner {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    background:url(../images/loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #000;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0
}`. The loader will show till the page loads.